# iOS app AdColony framework bad video orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, ads, adcolony

our iOS app is running in portrait mode only without a problem. I have set the following in the info.plist.xml

```
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

I now added AdColony framework to the project. Everything works good except when I rotate the device from portrait to landscape mode while watching the video: the video rotates. That's ok, but after the video has finished and it returns back to the app, it's broken (see screenshots). Somehow it's stuck in landscape mode. Can someone help me how can I fix it?

http://s9.postimg.org/dog11jywf/IMG_0040.png
http://s9.postimg.org/xkc0h3fxr/IMG_0041.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the AlertView lib. I use DLAVAlertView, when the video stopped an alert appears which detect the orientation changes, and messed up the layout. So I disable the orientation changes for the alert.

Answer (score 1):

AdColony videos don’t show in portrait on iPhones (landscape only) so, as long as you aren't rotating the device to the landscape orientation opposite to the one the video is playing in when you reorient your device, the video shouldn’t rotate. It sounds like you’re using an old version of our SDK that is not iOS 8 compatible. Please update to the latest version available on our [GitHub page](https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK). If you are still experiencing issues after that, please submit a support ticket to support@adcolony.com.

Comment: I know videos shows in landscape only. If I don't rotate the device everything is fine, but if I rotate the device while the video is showing, the view is sliding to the right bottom corner. [link](http://s9.postimg.org/dog11jywf/IMG_0040.png) When rotate again to landscape mode the video is showing in the right position.
I use the latest Sdk (2.5.0.5).

Comment: As we will need a full device log to further troubleshoot this, you must submit a support request to support@adcolony.com.